# How to init emacs with an option (such as `--debug-init`)

Tags: microsoft-windows, start-up

This might be a very silly question, and that's maybe why there's no answer on the internet.

I'm using Windows 10. And I tried to click on properties, and then change the ending of the file's name for `--debug-init` or `--no-window-system` and, of course, the .exe disappears.

I could get sites where there're lists of the Options available and their functions but not specifically how to use the Options.

Comment: Have you tried the way mentioned at the bottom of this [emacswiki](https://www.emacswiki.org/emacs/EmacsMsWindowsIntegration) ?

Comment: Yeah, but I end up with this http://prntscr.com/m8ia2i. It is my first techie experience, That's why it is a lot harder for me.

Comment: Your screenshot shows that you didn't do what @whatacold suggested (go to the *bottom* of [that EmacsWiki page](https://www.emacswiki.org/emacs/EmacsMsWindowsIntegration)). The suggestion is to use a Windows shortcut, and to put something like this in the `Target` field: `D:\path\to\runemacs.exe --debug-init`. (And it's a good question, not a silly one.)

Comment: @whatacold: Please consider posting your suggestion as an answer.

Comment: Sorry I skipped _bottom_ and I started to try to make what the whole site says. I figured it out. Thanks a lot!!!

Answer (score 1):

Try the method as mentioned at the bottom of this [EmacsWiki: Emacs Ms Windows Integration - www.emacswiki.org](https://www.emacswiki.org/emacs/EmacsMsWindowsIntegration) page:

1. Create a new shortcut to “emacs.exe”.
2. Right click newly created shortcut and choose properties.
3. In target field type: "X:\path\to\emacs\bin\emacs.exe" --debug-init
4. Close properties dialog.
5. Just click the shortcut to start Emacs with that option.

Go to that page to see more ways about integrating Emacs on MS Windows.